# Typescript - Restrict passing valid prop to a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Is it possible to restrict passing a valid prop to a react component?

Example:

```
<SomeComponent primaryCTA={<Button size="small">Click here</Button} />
```

Now, in the code above, I want to user to NOT be able to provide **size** prop.

This is how type Props of SomeComponent look like

```
type SomeComponentProps = {
  primaryCTA: React.ReactElement<
     Exclude<ButtonProps, 'size'>,
     typeof Button>;
}
```

But, the code above doesn't work. You can still provide size prop to Button component inside SomeComponent.

Comment: Try setting size: never, in ButtonProps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't restrict the type here because rendered JSX doesn't carry with it the type of the component that rendered it. This means that there is no type information to restrict:

```
const button = <Button size="small">foo</Button> // type: JSX.Element
```

Instead, it's usually best to let `SomeComponent` handle creating the button by exposing props about how to do that.

For example, if `primaryCTA` was typed as `string`, then in your `SomeComponent` rendering you could create the button:

```
function SomeComponent({ primaryCTA }: Props) {
  return <Button size="small-or-whatever">{primaryCTA}</Button>
}
```

---

Or you can make `primaryCTA` be the type of props that `Button` expects.

You can use `React.ComponentProps<typeof Button>` to get the prop types from the `Button` component, and then you can use `Omit<Props, 'size'>` to remove whatever you don't want to expose. Lastly, you can spread those props back into the button with `<Button {...primaryCTA} />`

Putting that together, you could do something like:

```
interface SomeComponentProps {
    primaryCTA: Omit<React.ComponentProps<typeof Button>, 'size'>
}

function SomeComponent({ primaryCTA }: SomeComponentProps) {
    return <>
        <div>Testing this component</div>
        <Button {...primaryCTA} size='small' />
    </>
}

// Usage of SomeComponent
<SomeComponent primaryCTA={{ color: 'red', children: 'click here!' }} />
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=73#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)